# Display image source where image path stored in database

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I need to display related image  in ngFor

Like

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let name of cheaterNames">
   <div class="col-4">
      {{ name.name }}
      <img src="{{name.path}}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how the data look like in database

```
  _id        OgjectId("566666tyyhhhh")
   name      Laravel
   path      uploads\logo.png
```

This how my project folder looks like

```
 Project
    client
      about
        about.component.html // this the html i used to display images
        about.component.ts
    dist
    e2e
    node_modules
    server //this is where express/nodejs
       controllers
       models
       routes
       app.ts 
    uploads // this is where the images is stored during file uploads
      logo.png
      other imgs...
```

Any ideas for this? The image does not show up and shows 404 error

Comment: What's the error

Comment: @Scriptonomy console shows 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths will all be relative to the base content directory for your web server which is probably not your project's home directory. Basically, the `uploads` directory is not within your base content directory, so your image files will not be found by the server at runtime. You need to determine where your base content directory is (express server configuration) and ensure that your uploads directory is under that directory.

For example, if you're serving up a build from the `dist` directory, `uploads` should be under `dist`;

Comment: The uploaded file is saved in a folder outside the server folder where app.ts is located. That is why the upload folder is never copied to dist folder. This is how I created the upload folder const DIR = './uploads/';
// const upload = multer({dest: DIR}).single('photo');
This code is located in app.ts, now how could I create the upload directory so that it will be created inside the server folder?